# Interesting Salesforce.com Blogs

Tags: force.com, knowledge, blogger

Could you suggest me interesting blogs about development on the Salesforce.com Platform?

I think its will be interesting not only for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest the following blog http://sf-ninja.blogspot.ru/

It grows on my eyes.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to learn is https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead

In trailhead you can learn so many things.

For related to docs

Visualforce doc https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/

Apex doc https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/

This is list of all developer docs. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs docs for salesforce devloper.

I personally suggest go with Trailhead then go with docs for more info.

If you google it with your basic requirement. You will able to find so many blog related to your requirement. If you have any query or issue while development.

Ask here in community with your code. In community so many members always will be ready to help you.

Good Luck